# Central VS Code server installer across multiple remotes

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote

I'm in a university with a very slow network, and I primarily develop on Docker or other WSL systems. As such, many times when I launch VS Code, it begins to update the server and takes half an hour to complete.

I *always* use Debian-like distros on the x64 architecture, so I can use the same installer for all these server instances. Is there a way I can stop it from downloading the same file again and again for each remote machine?

I want to unify just the download process that uses the internet; I'm happy to move the file around on my computer and install it separately in each distro (but I should at least be able to hack together a script to do this, if not make this supported directly by the editor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code already provides a built-in solution. Set `remote.SSH.allowLocalServerDownload`.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/115k8tu/comment/j92lnzx/?context=3